# Near Addresses based in current location

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I'm starting developer a app for windows phone 7.5. So this is the scenario:

- I have a list with a few addresses and I want get the nearest based in my current location (distance radius will be determine by the user in time to filter).

Anyone can point me a direction in how I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find some web service that can map an address to GPS coordinates and then calculate the distance. I guess bing map API and Google maps provides api:s for address lookup.

Once you have the coordinates you calculate distance by

```
var addressLocation = new GeoCoordinate(-51.39792, -0.12084);

var yourLocation = new GeoCoordinate(-29.83245, 31.04034);

double distance = addressLocation .GetDistanceTo(yourLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bing Maps SOAP Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966738.aspx